# no tables are added to database when using code first approach in Entity Framework 6

Tags: entity-framework

I have a need to add 2 tables to an exsisting database using Entity Framework 6. I have created the classes/tables in code, added DBSets in a new custom DBContext file, added a configuration and then I run the application. But the tables are not added to the database, what could be wrong here?

```
        public class TiDataDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<TiData> TiDatas { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TiDataLanguage> TiDataLanguages { get; set; }

        public TiDataDbContext() : base("name=TestServerDB")
        {
        }

        public static void Initialize()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<TiDataDbContext, TechDataMigrationsConfiguration>());
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            //Manage auto update database
            var update = true;
            if (update)
                Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<TiDataDbContext, TiDataMigrationsConfiguration>());
            else
                Database.SetInitializer<TiDataDbContext>(null);

            modelBuilder.Entity<TiDataLanguage>()
                .HasKey(tdl => new { tdl.Id, tdl.LanguageId, tdl.TiDataId });

            modelBuilder.Entity<TiDataLanguage>()
                .HasRequired(tdl => tdl.TiDatas)
                .WithMany(td => td.TiDataLanguages)
                .HasForeignKey(tdl => tdl.TiDataId);
        }
    }



config

    internal sealed class TiDataMigrationsConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<TiDataDbContext>
    {
        public TiDataMigrationsConfiguration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
            MigrationsDirectory = "Migrations";
            AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true; // Needed to be able to update tables
        }

        protected override void Seed(TiDataDbContext context)
        {
            context.TiDatas.Create();
            context.TiDataLanguages.Create();
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }


    [Table("Demo.TiData")]
    public class TiData
    {
        public int TiDataId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Unit { get; set; }

        public ICollection<TiDataLanguage> TiDataLanguages { get; set; }
    }


    [Table("Demo.TiDataLanguage")]
    public class TiDataLanguage
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int LanguageId { get; set; }
        public int TiDataId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Unit { get; set; }

        public TiData TiData { get; set; }
    }



global.asax

TiDataDbContext.Initialize();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `EnsureCreated` method in constructor:

```
public TiDataDbContext() : base("name=TestServerDB")
{
    Database.EnsureCreated();
}
```